# HttpClient Return error code 500 Server Internal Error

Tags: c#, httpclient

This is the method Making the call:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Session> GetSessionFromLoginAsync()
 {
   try
      {
         var client = CustomHttpClient.GetClient();
         var httpRequest = PrepareRequest(_host, HttpMethod.Post, _connParameters);
            try
                {
                  var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
                     if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                      {
                        throw CustomException.CreateExceptionFromResponseErrors(httpResponse);
                      }

                      if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                      {
                        return null;
                      }

                   var headers = httpResponse.Headers.ToString();
                   string keyRoute = "ROUTEID=";
                   int posRouteID = headers.IndexOf(keyRoute);
                   string routeID2End = headers.Substring(posRouteID + keyRoute.Length, headers.Length - posRouteID - keyRoute.Length);
                   int semiColumn = routeID2End.IndexOf(";");
                   var routeID = ";" + keyRoute + routeID2End.Substring(0, semiColumn);
                   string dataResult = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                   session = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionSL>(dataResult);
                   session.RouteID = routeID;
                    }
              catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _esito = SendError(_esito, e, Constants.ErrorCode.LoginError);
                }


                return session;
            }

public static HttpRequestMessage PrepareRequest(string host, HttpMethod method, object contentObj)
        {

            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contentObj);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate (object sender, X509Certificate cert,
                                                                               X509Chain chain,
                                                                               SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            { return true; };

            StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var HttpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(host),
                Method = method,
                Content = content
            };

            return HttpRequest;

        }
```

And this is CustomHttpClient class:

```
public sealed class CustomHttpClient
    {
        private static HttpClient _client;

        public static HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                var messageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseCookies = false,
            };

                //messageHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;
                //messageHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate (object sender, X509Certificate cert,
                                                                               X509Chain chain,
                                                                               SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                { return true; };

                _client = new HttpClient(messageHandler)
                {
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants._HTTP_TIMEOUT_SEC),
                    //BaseAddress = new Uri("myendpoint");
                };
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            }

            return _client;
        }
    }
```

My app is WFP...
What I do not understand is that the same methods I used to make an app in Xamarin Forms and I never received in the response the error http 500 ...
And I think there are no errors in the code .. and not even on the server because with tools like Postman I can easily connect and I always receive as a message "200 OK"...

Comment: 500 is a *server* fault. It means the *server* crashed. Perhaps the request it received caused an exception. HttpClient was release in 2012 and used by WPF long, long before Xamarin.Forms. Don't look for bugs in it. Check the server's logs.

Comment: It is not possible to determine why the error occurs if you don't show code which actually returned 500. The client has nothing to do with this. Show us the server-side code where the actual error happening

Comment: Use Fiddler and check what's actually sent to the server. BTW `jsonObj.ToString()` is calling `ToString()` on a string object

Comment: (This returned 500) var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);

Comment: I always find the same error from Xamarin using Windows Universal App..not with Android or iOS

Comment: I've also tested the code directly on the server and it does not change anything ... always 500 error

Comment: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  DataServiceVersion: 3.0
  Connection: close
  Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2018 14:41:47 GMT
  Set-Cookie: ROUTEID=.node3; path=/b1s
  Server: Apache/2.4.25
  Server: (Unix)
  Content-Length: 0
}

Comment: I try same code with Xamarin...the value of httpRequest is  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage   but in my application httpRequest's value is  {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://server:port/Login', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}